# simple php copy function always retuns an error

Tags: php, copy, lamp

I've been through this code several times and still can't see what's wrong.  This code is the contents of [url]/sig/index.php.  Every time I run it, I get "Sorry there was an error".  But when I check the values of the new and old files I'm trying to copy they're fine.  Am I doing something stupid?  I'm using the copy function in other pages on the same server so I'm sure it must be something wrong with the code.

This is a simple page to copy a file in the same directory, overwriting the previous file.  I know the source files exist because I have a "Test link to source file" that always works.

```
<?php

$formval = $_POST["banners"] ;
$newname = "banner-main.png" ;
$dir = "/sig/" ;

$img_to_copy = $dir . $formval . ".png" ;
$newimg =  $dir . $newname ;



if (copy($img_to_copy, $newimg)) {
        echo ($formval . " is the new email signature image.") ;
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error.";
        } ;

echo '<a href="' . $img_to_copy . '?var=' . rand(0,1000000) . '" target="_blank">Test link to source file</a>' ;

?> 



<h1>Which banner is next?</h1>

<br>

      <form action="/sig/index.php" method="post">
         <input type="radio" name="banners" value="banner-1">Banner 1
         <br>
         <input type="radio" name="banners" value="banner-2">Banner 2
         <br>
         <input type="radio" name="banners" value="banner-3">Banner 3
         <br>
         <input type="radio" name="banners" value="banner-4">Banner 4
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
```

Comment: Most likely the `$dir = "/sig/"` you have there. When viewing the file (in HTML) this uses the folder `sig/` from the _DocumentRoot_ of your domain/project. When copying this will use the folder `sig/` from your _filesystem_ root (where the file doesn't exist). Change it to ``$dir = "./sig/"`` or use a full _filesystem path_ when copying

Comment: @kerbholz That worked - if you'd like to add your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the cause of your problem is `$dir = "/sig/"` you have there.

When viewing the file (in HTML) this uses the folder `sig/` from the *web server DocumentRoot* of your domain/project.

When copying this will use the folder `sig/` from your *filesystem root* (where the file doesn't exist).

Change `$dir = "/sig/"` to `$dir = "./sig/"` or use a *full filesystem path* when copying the file.